# Disable automagic CakePHP Auth login() action

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I want to do some stuff in the users/login action before login user.

For example i have captcha code on each 3rd submit of the login form and i want to check if the captcha code is valid. If it is not valid i want user to fill it up correctly first, before is able to submit. And if captcha is ok i want to use Auth->login()

Unfortunately when submit the form Auth->data['User']['username'] and Auth->data['User']['password'] are filled and the login is done behind(automagically)...

How can i disable automagically user login of the Auth component and do that only from Auth->login($data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write - like I did (with similar captcha stuff) - your own AuthExt component (or name it whatever you like) which extends the Auth Component

then override the login() method so that it suits your need

Answer (score 1):

One option, depending on your project, is to upgrade to CakePHP 2.0 as there the auto-magic behavior has been removed, see [Identifying users and logging them in](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in).

Answer (score 1):

one hack is to set the Auth->loginAction to a non-existent action (non-existent so that no one can access that), so Auth won't auto login in login(), you can do your own logic in there (password hashing is still automatically applied).

Comment: Another hack I done is to logout the user, do your stuff and then login.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
function beforeFilter(){
}
```

in this function u can do all things that want before anything happens in your controller.